# Using Regex to strip HTML and ampersand (&quot; &amp;) tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am pulling HTML code from a news page (within the same site) and am wanting to strip all the HTML tags from it. At present, all tags have beens stripped, except for special characters (&") etc. I have scoured all of the stackoverflow posts, and couldn't find anything that works. Perhaps it is the way I am defining the function.

I have tried using multiple variances to the - item.cleanedHtml = item.PublishingPageContent.replace(/</?[^>]+>/gi, '');

But the result either adds the HTML tags back, or doesn't display the text at-all. Within the [] I have tried adding " or just & to see if that would help. I have also tried changing the complete line with varying other suggestions that I could find, to no avail.

```
_blah.controller('myNewsController', ['$scope','newsService', function($scope,newsService) {
        newsService.getNews().then(function(newsItems){
            for (var i = 0; i < newsItems.length; i++) {
                var item = newsItems[i]; 
                item.cleanedHtml = item.PublishingPageContent.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
                item.cleanedHtmlFun = item.cleanedHtml.replace(/"/gi, '').replace(/'/gi, '');
                item.imageUrl = getImageUrlfromSrc(item.File.Properties.PublishingPageImage,item);
            }
            $scope.news = newsItems;            
        });
    }]);
```

I expect the output to read: As reported by Tom & Jerry 
"What I am getting is: As reported by Tom &amp; Jerry"

Comment: `As reported by Tom &amp; Jerry`.replace(/\&amp;/g, '')` you can use this to replace `&`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow...you will see this answer pop up quite often: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4665

Comment: @CodeManiac - thank you for that! The only thing that I needed to change was to remove the "&", as it was completely stripping it out (as expected behavior for the .replace function).

Comment: My completed code for that line goes like this:

item.cleanedHtml = item.PublishingPageContent.replace(/<\/?[^p>]+>/gi, '').replace(/<[\/]p+>/gi, '').replace(/<\/p+>/gi, ' ').replace(/"/gi, '').replace(/'/gi, '').replace(/<\/?[p>]+>/gi, ' ');

Comment: This works even better (and looks a lot cleaner): item.cleanedHtml = item.PublishingPageContent.replace(/<(.|\n)+?>/gi, ' ');